# Работа с WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Кто подскажет где здесь ошибка?

Код должен искать значение в первом столбце который в базе данных является ключом и допускается только числа,а вот код при поиске 56 и 5656 обрабатывает и выделяет как равными строками в datagridview.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)

              if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.RosyBrown;
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contains - ищет подстроку в строке и логично, что при поиске 56, значение "56" и "5656" его содержат. Используйте более точное сравнение, если хотите получать идентичные значения.

```
if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text))
...
```

Comment: спасибо,уже сделал ;)